# How do I execute a Stored Procedure in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, .net

Using the following SQL Stored Procedure, how would I execute it within the event handler of the `btnYes` Button? I don't know how to execute Stored Procedures. I have a `TextBox` set up to input the `RoomNo`. When I click `btnYes`, the expected outcome should be that the `Occupied` boolean is set to `true` in the `tblRooms` table based on it's `RoomNo`.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE sproc_tblRooms_Update
    -- Parameters for the UPDATE statement
    @RoomNo   INT,
    @Occupied BIT
AS
    UPDATE tblRooms
    SET Occupied = @Occupied
    WHERE RoomNo = @RoomNo
```

`Update()` method set up in a class:

```
public void Update(clsRoom RoomOccupancy)
{
    // This function will update an existing reservation in the database

    // Connect to the database
    clsDataConnection DBRoomVacancy = new clsDataConnection();

    // Add the parameters
    DBRoomVacancy.AddParameter("@RoomNo", RoomOccupancy.RoomNo);
    DBRoomVacancy.AddParameter("@Occupied", RoomOccupancy.Occupied);

    // Execute the query
    DBRoomVacancy.Execute("sproc_tblRooms_Update");
}
```

Event handler for the `btnYes` button that I want to click to execute the Stored Procedure:

```
protected void btnYes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: its a little strange!!! create instance of class that have update method in btnYes_Click and call the method in  for update!

Comment: Is `clsDataConnection` a custom class you defined? I can't find any documentation for it...

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do, however I don't have experience or knowledge in doing it. Feel free to edit the event handler for btnYes_Click to something that might work for returning the Boolean as true when the query is executed, thanks.

Comment: Yes, I have my own class for Data Connection. Here's the link for the code if you care to look at it - http://www.cse.dmu.ac.uk/~mjdean/notes/modules/Shared%20Content/DataConnection/DataConnection.txt

Comment: I'm baffled by how often this week I've been seeing .net developers on stack overflow using Hungarian notation.  Who's teaching people to use this?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to call the `Update()` method after creating an instance of the class that the `Update()` method is a member of. Since you didn't provide the full class definition, I'm just going to call it `MyClass` in the example below:

```
protected void btnYes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var myClass = new MyClass();
    myClass.Update(new clsRoom
    {
        RoomNo = 1234,
        Occupied = true
    });
}
```

That being said, as an off-topic note, your [`clsDataConnection`](http://www.cse.dmu.ac.uk/~mjdean/notes/modules/Shared%20Content/DataConnection/DataConnection.txt) class needs a lot of work. I didn't look at it long, but what jumped out at me is that none of the classes that implement [`IDisposable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable?view=netframework-4.8) (like [`SqlConnection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection?view=netframework-4.8), [`SqlCommand`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand?view=netframework-4.8), etc) are wrapped in a [`using`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/using-objects) block or call [`Dispose()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable.dispose?view=netframework-4.8).

I also notice that the class uses a shared instance of `SqlConnection` for all of it's queries. Best practice is to [create one instance of `SqlConnection` per query](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/142068/200248).

I would also invert some of your `if` statements and use `return` to get rid of some of your unnecessary `else` blocks. The reason for this is to reduce unnecessary nesting and avoid the [Pyramid of Doom](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CoYUZ3cUIAEx7XR.jpg)/[Arrow code](https://blog.codinghorror.com/flattening-arrow-code/).

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class news : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 

    }
    protected void btnYes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            string str = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str );
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sproc_tblRooms_Update", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@RoomNo", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txttitle.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Occupied ", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Occupied.SelectedValue.ToString();
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            lblmsg.Text = "Room has been Updated Successfully";
        }
        catch (Exception)
        { }
    }
}
```